# Discarding commits at the end of the repo sync?

Tags: android, git, github, synchronization, repo

I just commited 2 changes in /frameworks/base, but when I type `repo sync -f -j5` at the end of the sync the changes are gone and it says

> Fetching projects: 100% (494/494), done.
>
> Syncing work tree: 100% (494/494), done.
>
> frameworks/base/: discarding 2 commits

In frameworks/base I just did `git fetch /repo/project`, `git cherry-pick xxxxx` and `git commit`. Nothing else.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

*repo sync -f* will convert to a detached header status.

you can enter /frameworks/base, use command *git branch -a* to find the branch you just commit in. and *git checkout* to switch to it.